# WPF / C#, how can we control the playback of synchronous frames of videos with SemaphoreSlim (signal)?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, parallel-processing, semaphore

**Project Details:**
In this **WPF** project, video is displayed on the number of structures.
In fact, it is a kind of simulator that simulates the display of video on the LEDs installed on the structure or building.

```
private async Task PlayBinAsync()
    {
        InitBinList();

        if (animPlayingMode == AnimPlayingMode.ParallelSynchronous)
        {
            List<Task> runningTasks = new List<Task>();
            Coordinator.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < Products.Count; i++)
            {
                Coordinator.Add(0);
                Task runningTask = ReadDisplayBinFrames(Products[i], true);
                runningTasks.Add(runningTask);

                #if DEBUG
                Debug.WriteLine($"LedProducts Count: {Products[i].LastFrameRead} of Product {i}");
                #endif
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(runningTasks);
        }
        
    }

public async Task ReadDisplayBinFrames(Product product, bool PlayMode)
    {
        BinFile.SetPlayMode(PlayMode);
        while (BinFile.IsPlayMode)
        {
            for (int currentFrameNumber = product.LastFrameRead; currentFrameNumber <= product.BinFiles.TotalGame; currentFrameNumber++)
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    product.BinFiles.GetSphereColorFromBin(product.BinFiles.GetFrame(currentFrameNumber), product.Wiring);
                    product.LastFrameRead = currentFrameNumber;
                    #if DEBUG
                    Debug.WriteLine($"LastFrameRead {product.LastFrameRead}");
                    #endif
                    product.Wiring.SetSphereColor(product.DelayPlay);
                });
                Coordinator[product.ProductId] += 1;
                await AllowPlayAsync(Coordinator);
                if (currentFrameNumber >= product.BinFiles.TotalGame)
                {
                    product.LastFrameRead = 0;
                }

                if (animPlayingMode == AnimPlayingMode.SerialAsync)
                {
                    BinFile.SetPlayMode(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
private async Task AllowPlayAsync(List<int> input)
    {
        if (input.All(o => o == input[0]))
        {
            signal.Release();
        }
        else
        {
            await signal.WaitAsync();
        }
    }
List<int> Coordinator = new List<int>();
private SemaphoreSlim signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
```

**Project requirements:**

1- I want all the structures or buildings to run the videos in unison and not even one frame behind or one frame forward.
2- The project should run continuously and should not stop playing the video until it stops.

In order for the frames to be executed together on the structures, I store the number of executed frames in a list and wait for all the frames to meet and become one using the AllowPlayAsync method. It is equalized, the work continues.

But unfortunately it does not work properly!

Comment: What exactly is not working? Could you minimize your example to the essence of the problem?

Comment: Also, I don't think that synchronizing LED playback between multiple LED walls down to fractions of a second is something that can purely be solved by considering your C# code alone. There are other things to consider: the LEDs itself (all the same make & model?), the communication from your software to the different LED controllers, etc.

Comment: Since a picture is worth a thousand words,  [link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/kfus18kzax6502u/Captured+From+Software.zip/file) . First of all, this project is only a simulator and it is not supposed to be directly connected to the LEDs, and it only takes a special output from the input videos and the output is transferred to the LEDs.
Secondly, since the execution of the frames do not end together due to various reasons, the frames that have finished must wait until the rest of the frames finish, but when they stop, I don't know how to start them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I modified and optimized the previous code as follows:
This code **works well** and **accurately**, but if I want one of the products to work separately or separately from other products, it will not work and it will immediately coordinate with other products. I decided to use the **"Products list"** instead of the **"Coordinator list"**, but for unknown reasons, after running the **AllowPlayAsync** method for a few frames, it gets stuck in the wait mode and does not exit from this mode.

```
private volatile static SemaphoreSlim signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
public volatile static ObservableCollection<Product> Products;

private void ImportProducts()
        {
            // After Import Products
            // The number of members in the Products Collection should be equal to the number of members in the Products list.
            Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        }

public async Task ReadDisplayBinFrames(Product product, bool PlayMode)
        {
            product.BinFiles.IsPlayMode = PlayMode;
                for (int currentFrameNumber = product.LastFrameRead; currentFrameNumber <= product.BinFiles.TotalGame && product.BinFiles.IsPlayMode; currentFrameNumber++)
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        product.LastFrameRead = currentFrameNumber;
                        AllowPlayAsync();

                        product.BinFiles.GetSphereColorFromBin(product.BinFiles.GetFrame(currentFrameNumber), product.Wiring);
#if DEBUG
                        Debug.WriteLine($"LastFrameRead {product.LastFrameRead} - PlayMode: {product.BinFiles.IsPlayMode}");
#endif

                        SetSphereColor(product.Wiring,product.DelayPlay);

                        if (currentFrameNumber >= product.BinFiles.TotalGame)
                        {
                            product.LastFrameRead = currentFrameNumber = -1;
                        }

                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                        {
                            if (animPlayingMode == AnimPlayingMode.SerialAsync)
                            {
                                product.BinFiles.IsPlayMode = false;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
        }


private void AllowPlayAsync()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (Coordinator.ToList().All(o => o == Coordinator[0]))
                {
                    signal.Release();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    signal.Wait();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think a semaphore is the correct solution.

If you have a single process that should show a number of synchronized images, just use a single thread that picks images from each of the sources and sends the list of frames to the UI thread.

You could use a [BlockingCollections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-7.0)  for each video stream. i.e. use one task/thread for each video stream to generate frames, and use a fairly low 'upperBound' to block the generating thread one you have a sufficient buffer.

The single thread would then take one image from each collection. If an image is not yet available, the thread will block until it is. Once you have a image from each collection, send over all the images to the UI thread for updating.

I'm no WPF expert, but I think wpf keeps a separate rendering thread, so it might be possible for rendering to occur while the main thread is updating the images. If you need better guarantees you may have to merge all the images to one large image, or do some other OS-magic to block the rendering thread.

Comment: Can you give an example with this method for my problem?

Comment: @KeyvanSFX A complete example would be more than I'm willing to write. But if you are familiar with blocking collections and other common multi threading practices it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: I have 2 main problems with the BlockingCollection class: First, I need to constantly update the members of this collection using index, which apparently does not support index. Secondly, when I compare the elements of this set using the linq command, even though they are all the same, the condition does not become true. I think that the values are compared by reference type
if (Coordinator.All(o => o == Coordinator[0]))

Comment: @KeyvanSFX The blocking collection is intended to provide a synchronized buffer between the image producing threads and the UI. Not to actually hold images for any length of time, so your UI thread should *take* images from the buffer, not index it. And I'm really not sure what your linq example is supposed to show, reference types are compared by reference by default, but why would you expect all items to be equal.